# Has anyone else seen '/online-test.json' in their access logs?

Tags: json, http-status-code-404, access-log

We have been getting a ton of 404's looking for the above. We have verified that this is coming from a valid user but we cannot see what is actually looking for this file.

This continues even when the user is not logged in and this is the only user that is sending this request. I thought chrome plugins could be the culprit but I have yet to find one to reproduce the issue.

This is coming from 1 user. Consistently 5-6 times per minute as a GET. We do not have this file anywhere in our code base.

Comment: Started happening for me too.

Comment: Happening here too, to the point of causing some users to hit our rate limiting caps :/